# Ember.js: action with explicit target fails

Tags: ember.js, action, target, mixins

I guess I'm missing something really basic, but the following fails with `The action 'login' did not exist on App.AppController`.

Template:

```
<h2>Click the button and watch the console</h2>
<button type="button" {{action login target="App.AppController"}}>Log in</button>
```

Controller:

```
App.AppController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  login: function() {
    // never gets here
    debugger;
  },
  send: function() {
    // or even here
    debugger;
  }
});
```

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/okuqiv/5/edit (this is pointing to Ember latest, but it's the same behavior with 1.0-rc2, the version I've been using for a couple of days; I haven't tried it on previous versions).

Upon debugging, it seems that somehow the controller mixin is not exposing all the functions it should -- login() is a function I added, but send() is an Ember function. It's also missing other functions like get().

I saw that in my app the login() function exists on the object App.AppController.prototype, while in the JSBin it exists on one of the objects in the mixin chain.

At this point I'd even be happy to handle the login action in the view, or the router (as it seems it was the default in the past), but none of those seem to work.

From the documentation, the current default place where the actions handlers should live is the controller anyway, and then the routes, but if I remove the target and add login() to the route, I get another error: `Nothing handled the event 'login'` (I'm using the target in the first place because in my app /login is a separate route and has a different controller).

Solutions and workaround will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are targeting the class App.AppController and not an actual instance of that class. If you are using the router and are in an app view then action would target the appController by default.

I've updated the JSbin to call login on the IndexController since your example is in the index  route:

http://jsbin.com/okuqiv/10/

You were also over riding the send method which was preventing login from being called.

Comment: I got the answer in IRC a short time ago. You are half right, I am targeting the definition/singleton, and not the instance, but the question was how to target a different controller (the jsbin was simplified for the sake of example), and the answer to that question is to use {{action login target="controllers.app"}}.

Comment: The final solution also requires that the controller in the context f the action has a needs: ['app'], so that the action can be handled by the AppController.